# Android studio : Can not choose signature version

Tags: android, signature

I want to build my app with V1 & V2 signature version. But both of them are greyed out. Can anyone please tell me how to make it avaiable to choose?
[generate signature]

Answer (score 7):

As described in the [official document](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2),

> Android 7.0 introduces APK Signature Scheme v2, a new app-signing scheme that offers faster app install times and more protection against unauthorized alterations to APK files. By default, **Android Studio 2.2** and the Android Plugin for **Gradle 2.2** sign your app using both APK Signature Scheme v2 and the traditional signing scheme, which uses JAR signing.

So be sure that the **android studio** and the **gradle plugin of module**(build.gradle->com.android.tools.build:gradle) are updated to **2.3 and above**.

Comment: Updating Gradle to 2.3  (2.3.3) solved this issue for me; I could select both signature versions V1 and V2.

Comment: I have created my keystore in older Android studio and app is already in play store. Can I upgrade my keystore file?

Comment: @shantanu You can use the old keystore file, what changed is the signature method, not the keystore structure. Besides, it doesn't matter not to upgrade your app keystore, your app can still run on Android 7.0.

Answer (score 5):

Updating Android Studio and Gradle version worked for me.

Also check your build.gradle and configure it. More information here [APK Signature Scheme v2](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2)

Answer (score 0):

Basically your Android studio is updated, 
but gradle plugin of module `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle'` version is downgrade in build.gradle.
So please update the version of gradle plugin like this:

```
dependencies{
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
 }
```

or above in build.gradle. and Sync the project. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

one reason could be that if you build your project there are some problems. fix the errors and start creating your signs.