# Error while upload the apk in google play console

Tags: android, console, playback

You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: MIN_SIG_SCHEME_FOR_TARGET_SDK_NOT_MET: Target SDK version 30 requires a minimum of signature scheme v2; the APK is not signed with this or a later signature scheme

Answer (score 0):

You need to update version min 30

```
  compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.xxxxd"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: Sir, same problem

Answer (score 0):

when signing apk it will show you signature versions below remember to check V2 Full APK Signature or start using AAB

[image: check V2 Full signature down below]

V2 Signing is minimum Signature Scheme as of now and V3 is also on the line for more details refer [this link](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v3) and to know more about app signing refer [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing).

Comment: Sir,V1 and v2 signature are disable and not tickable in my case.

Comment: which version of android studio and android gradle plugin are you using ? also try updating gradle plugin to latest stable 4.2.2

Comment: same issue was already faced by others you can find more details at https://stackoverflow.com/q/43525209/8968956

Comment: 3.3.2 android studio

Comment: after change the gradle version

Comment: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs$TaskInputUnionFileCollection cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

Comment: The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: i think issue here is related to your android studio and gradle plugin so try reinstalling newer version of android studio and try again latest stable version is 4.2.2